# Filled area in 3d in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a 3D heat map in gnuplot. I would like to plot a filled area on top of it.
The datafile looks the following

```
118.01363   0.31794
139.62999   0.31216
173.51509   0.30177
210.90555   0.28675
244.79065   0.26942
268.15969   0.25209
293.86563   0.23764
318.40312   0.21974
341.77215   0.20414
303.21324   0.28270
292.69718   0.29194
279.25998   0.30350
254.13827   0.31794
234.27459   0.31967
173.51509   0.31563
153.65141   0.31274
139.62999   0.31216
```

I know how to get the result in 2d using `plot 'data' w filledcurve`, which gives the following result:

[image]

However, I cannot figure out how to plot it equivalently on a 3d map. I tried, e.g., `splot 'data' u 1:2:(1) w filledcurve` in order to obtain filledarea at constant value of z=1 but it does not do the job and it basically shows lines in z-axis direction:

[image]

Howe can I fill the area from the example at a constant value of z-axis on top of a pm3d map plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot style `with polygons` works in both 2D and 3D plots. You can provide a constant z value of zero or some other value to make sure the polygon sits in front of or behind whatever else is in the plot.

```
$Data << EOD
118.01363   0.31794
139.62999   0.31216
173.51509   0.30177
210.90555   0.28675
244.79065   0.26942
268.15969   0.25209
293.86563   0.23764
318.40312   0.21974
341.77215   0.20414
303.21324   0.28270
292.69718   0.29194
279.25998   0.30350
254.13827   0.31794
234.27459   0.31967
173.51509   0.31563
153.65141   0.31274
139.62999   0.31216
EOD

splot $Data using 1:2:(0) with polygon, '' using 1:2:(0) with lp lw 4
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, interesting! Available since gnuplot 5.4. Haven't used polygons so far. How well does such a polygon work together with another "3D"-surface?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this sounds like a simple task, however, I am not aware that you can easily draw filledcurves in 3D.
gnuplot `help filledcurves` explicitly mentions that this is only a 2D plotting style. Although, there is `zerrorfill` (check `help zerrorfill`) which allows to draw [fence plots](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/fenceplot.html), but there seems to be no `xyerrorfill`.

So, it seems you have to create a point grid out of your data for being able to plot a surface `with pm3d`.
If your path or area is not too special you could create a grid by adding points ranging from the mean x,y coordinate to your curve (i.e. like a spider web).

However, the result together with another surface is not satisfying at all. The surface is not nicely hidden behind the other curve. Maybe increasing `N` or interpolating along the path might help but will take much longer.

I hope very much that there are better solutions.

**Script:**

```
### attempt of filledcurved in 3D
reset session

$Data <<EOD
118.01363   0.31794
139.62999   0.31216
173.51509   0.30177
210.90555   0.28675
244.79065   0.26942
268.15969   0.25209
293.86563   0.23764
318.40312   0.21974
341.77215   0.20414
303.21324   0.28270
292.69718   0.29194
279.25998   0.30350
254.13827   0.31794
234.27459   0.31967
173.51509   0.31563
153.65141   0.31274
139.62999   0.31216
EOD

set table $myGrid
    stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput
    N = 20
    do for [i=0:N] {
        x0(x) = (x-STATS_mean_x)*i/N + STATS_mean_x
        y0(y) = (y-STATS_mean_y)*i/N + STATS_mean_y
        plot $Data u (x0($1)):(y0($2)) w table
        plot '+' u ("") every ::0::0 w table      # insert empty line
    }
unset table

f(x,y)=sin(0.1*x)+cos(50*y)

set pm3d hidden noborder depthorder
set samples 100,100
set isosamples 100,100
set key noautotitle
set cbrange [-2:2]
set view 35,30

set multiplot layout 2,1

    splot $myGrid u 1:2:(0):(0xff0000) w l lc rgb var
    
    splot f(x,y) w pm3d, \
          $myGrid u 1:2:(0):(0xff00ff) w pm3d lc rgb var
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:** (first plot `with lines` "spider web", second plot `with pm3d` and another surface)

[image]